# Build JMeter plan automatically every 90 min

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing

I have a JMeter test plan and I need to run JMeter and build the plan automatically every 90 minutes. Is there a way to do that?

Note : I use Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux you can use Cron where you need to specify schedule, path to jmeter.sh and path to your test-plan. Here are some examples for time format http://www.ubuntututorials.com/use-crontab-ubuntu/ Otherwise you can use Jenkins (for both Linux or Windows) and specify schedule there.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I am using Windows 8.1. I have updated the post

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should take a look at Jenkins. (http://jenkins-ci.org/). There is an article on it's wiki "Use Jenkins" that could help you to understand how it works and how to install it.

Comment: Please provide a relevant link/reference to Jenkins.

Comment: Please edit it into your answer instead of posting another comment.

Comment: @user2034269 And how? Share please it with us.

Comment: @olyv I posted my solution, hope that can help the others

Answer (score 0):

I have created a batch file and wrote small script using some Windows commands. After that I have created a basic task in Windows Task Scheduler and for this task setup the batch file has been added and the time to run JMeter automatically has been selected.